# Oracle forms 11: Changing label of tab page very slow

Tags: performance, tabs, oracleforms

I have a tab page in oracle forms. On the first tab, I have a master table. The master table has a few detail tables, which I show on other tab pages.

I would like to show the amount of records of the detail table, in the label of the tab page.

I change the labels in the *when new record instance* trigger of the master table. The problem is that

```
set_tab_page_property('CANVAS.DETAIL', label, 'Detail (' || amount || ')');
```

is extremely slow.

In Oracle Forms 6i, the change happens in a blink of an eye, in Oracle Forms 11, it takes about 8 seconds to load the new lables of the tab pages.

Does anyone have an idea how I can improve the performance of set_tab_page_property in Oracle Forms 11?

Comment: Have you checked to change this without any query and just changing the label. It seems to me your query is just slow and it is not the label change that is slow.

Comment: The query isn't slow, I've checked it with query and without query, I've put a messagebox between the query and the set_tab_page_property to test. Even if I remove the query, remove the value 'amount' from the label, the set_tab_page_property built in function is still very slow.

In Oracle Forms 6i it always goes very fast, with query and without query. In Oracle Forms 11 it's very slow.

Comment: I've got applications where I change multiple applications all the time it ain't slow, so it should be something else, but can't think of something else then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the following solution:

```
hide_view('CANVAS_TAB');
set_tab_page_property('CANVAS_TAB.MY_TAB', label, 'TAB Label (' || :global.row_count || ')');
show_view('CANVAS_TAB');
```

Principle is to hide canvas before to change label and display it again after. There is no blink effect at exec time. it works fine in my case.
Let try and revert.

Answer (score 1):

This is extremly slow when changing label of active tab.
Change the active tab (if possible) before to change label.